# Запросить ввод для EditText внутри recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-edittext

Есть resyclerView, состоящий из editText внутри ViewHolder. Для конфигурации каждого элемента в списке - каждого editText используется ViewModel, которая строится на сущности Field - некоторая информация о пользователе. Field может быть name, lastName, phone, email итд. В onBind адаптера мы назначаем viewModel для ViewHolder, чем добиваемся определенного построения элемента списка - иконка, тип поля итд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача - обеспечить переход по нажатию Enter на следующее поле ввода. Для полей о которых мы знаем все делается просто

```
   new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (actionId == 45) {
                // request focus for next field
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Здесь же ситуация получается такая, что Адаптер имеет представление только о массиве Fields и где то внутри себя ребиндит ViewHolder'ы на их основе внутри onBind, то есть это единственное место, где мы можем добавить обработку перехода с поля на поле по Enter, но там у нас есть доступ только к текущему ViewHolder. ViewHolder и TextField (кастомный EditText с рисунка) уж тем более не знают о других ViewHolder'ах и TextField'ах. Каким образом можно осуществить переход по Enter на следующее поле в таком случае?

Comment: А Вы уверены в целесообразности использования `RecyclerView` в данном случае? Сколько у вас `EditText`'ов?

Comment: @post_zeew этот экран используется в двух случаях. В первом от 10 до 18 полей, вот втором добавляется 4 поля и соответственно получается от 14 до 22 полей (разброс, потому что емейл и телефон могут множиться до определенного предела, что тоже говорит в пользу recycler view)

Comment: Вы можете отлавливать нажатия `Enter` в `EditText` и по нему делать переход к следующему пункту в `RecyclerView` путем вызова `scrollToPosition(int position)` у его `LayoutManager`.